# Undefined method 'actions' for Formtastic::FormBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, formtastic

I have rails 3.1.3 and formtastic 2.0.2.

I'm using the most basic form you can imagine:

```
 <%= semantic_form_for @customer do |f| %>
   <%= f.inputs %>
   <%= f.actions %>   
 <% end %>
```

I get the following error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 652ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `actions' for #<Formtastic::FormBuilder:0x00000128249018>):
    2: 
    3: <%= semantic_form_for @customer do |f| %>
    4:     <%= f.inputs %>
    5:     <%= f.actions %>
    6:   <% end %>
  app/views/customers/new.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_customers_new_html_erb___3455593051620241935_2485943640'
  app/views/customers/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_customers_new_html_erb___3455593051620241935_2485943640'
```

When I comment out **f.actions**, the form works.

Tried everything I could find, but I'm very much stuck at this point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently version 2.0.2 of formtastic does not support f.actions. Use f.buttons or upgrade formtastic to 2.1.0.beta1 which I do not recommend you as it is beta and was released some days ago.

Comment: Thank you sir. I copied the code fragments directly from the Github page. I replaced it with f.buttons and now it does work.

Comment: I get an `undefined method 'action' for #<Formtastic::FormBuilder:0x007f81ea7d99c0>`

Comment: which verison of formtastic are you using?

Comment: but how to add a class to a submit button?

Comment: try with :input_html => { :class => 'your_class' }

Comment: http://rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/master/Formtastic/Helpers/ButtonsHelper:buttons helped me out